# i need it to add one hour to HH:MM:SS but it becomes AM when it is supposed to be PM

Tags: c++, if-statement, time

I need help with my code the time when I hit 1 on my if statement shows in main(). It is AM when it is supposed to be PM. I believe it is getting hung up from my GET12Hour, and Get24hour functions, because when I switch the calls to me functions it works just fine but both don't output 24 hour clocks than 12 hours. How do I fix this. this is my first project in C++. please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

void Get24Hour(){
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm* lt = localtime(&now);

    cout << lt->tm_hour << ":";
    cout << lt->tm_min << ":";
    cout << lt->tm_sec;
    return;

}

void Get12Hour(){
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm* lt = localtime(&now);
    string amOrPm;

    if(lt->tm_hour > 12){
        lt->tm_hour = lt->tm_hour - 12;
        amOrPm = "PM";
        cout << lt->tm_hour << ":";
    }
    else{
        cout << lt->tm_hour << ":";
        amOrPm = "AM";
    }
    cout << lt->tm_min << ":";
    cout << lt->tm_sec << " ";
    cout << amOrPm;
    return;
}
void DisplayMenu(){
    cout << "1- Add One Hour" << endl;
    cout << "2- Add One Minute" << endl;
    cout << "3- Add One Second" << endl;
    cout << "4- Exit Program" << endl;
}

int main()
{

    time_t now = time(0);
    tm* lt = localtime(&now);
    string amOrPm;
    int userInput;

    cout << "24 hour clock" << endl;
    Get24Hour();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "12 hour clock" << endl;
    Get12Hour();
    cout << endl;

    DisplayMenu();


    cin >> userInput;
    if(userInput == 1){
        lt->tm_hour = lt->tm_hour + 1;
        cout << "24 hour clock" << endl;
        cout << lt->tm_hour << ":" << lt->tm_min << ":" << lt->tm_sec <<endl;

        cout << "12 hour clock" << endl;
        if(lt->tm_hour > 12){
            lt->tm_hour = lt->tm_hour - 12;
            amOrPm = "PM";
            cout << lt->tm_hour << ":";
        }
        else{
            cout << lt->tm_hour << ":";
            amOrPm = "AM";
        }
        cout << lt->tm_min << ":";
        cout << lt->tm_sec << " ";
        cout << amOrPm;
    }
    else if(userInput == 2){

    }
    else if (userInput == 3){

    }
    else if(userInput == 4){

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have logic errors and output format errors. Please consider using [`strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) function instead. It provides AM/PM designation by default.

Answer (score 0):

The cppreference.com documentation for [`localtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) says that it returns a

> pointer to a static internal `std::tm` object on success, or null pointer otherwise. The structure may be shared between `std::gmtime`, `std::localtime`, and `std::ctime`, and may be overwritten on each invocation.

The "static" means that it will be the same `std::tm` object every time. All your `lt` pointers point at the same struct. Every time `localtime` is called, the contents of that single object are changed to match that call's input.

So your program, in order:

1. Gets the `lt` pointer in `main`, and sets the `tm` object to the current time.
2. Gets and prints the local time in `Get24Hour`.
3. Calls `localtime` in `Get12Hour`. Then if the local time is in the afternoon, it *changes* the `std::tm` object, subtracting 12 from `tm_hour`.
4. Uses the `lt` pointer in `main` to print that time. Since this `lt` points at the same object which was just changed, this code sees the `tm_hour` value less than 12.

To fix this, make sure every call of `localtime` is close to where you use it, not with other functions in between which might also call `localtime`, `gmtime`, or `ctime`.

Comment: how would i do that. i am so lost on how to do that. do i need to take them out of each additional function other than my 12 hour clock and 24 hour clock. how would make the time  of my add hour function equal my 12 and 24 hour clocks plus one hour.